# Get name of ringtone assigned to a contact?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible for me to programmatically get the name of a ringtone assigned to a contact? Also, the timestamp of when the ringtone was assigned?

Comment: Please can you tell me what this has to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - there is no property to read or set the ringtone under Apple's privacy guidelines.